# C++ can't compile dll using GDI+

Tags: c++, gdi+

My TestDLL.cpp code looks like this:

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
    __declspec(dllexport) void test();
#else
    __declspec(dllimport) void test();
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

void test()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
}
```

Now when im trying to compile the dll there are 100+ errors from header files of GDI+.
However the GDI+ works(compiles) fine on my console application (exe). Isn't GDI+ compatible with DLL's or what? And the gdiplus.lib is linked incase someone asks it...

Comment: Can you paste the errors or should I use my crystal ball?

Comment: Stuff above `#include "stdafx.h"` is being ignored... also try and choose a better name for your precompiled header file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  The following line fixed it.

```
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Put this inside your precompiled header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors are likely due to invalid macros defined, see this [MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922323)

Comment: Also, platform headers that never change should be included from inside the precompiled header.  Otherwise there's no point to even having a precompiled header.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add gdi+ to the libraries your project is linking against. Check the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Lines like `using namespace gdiplus;` are dangerous in that they pull everything from that namespace into the current namespace.  This can lead to problems linking when you're building a DLL.

It's also possible that one of those headers is using the same `DLL_EXPORTS`

But a sampling of the first few error messages would make it a lot easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also came here after getting numerous errors when compiling my DLL using GDI+. However, none of the answers applied to my case.
Reason for my getting errors in my DLL was defining the macro WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN.
So, make sure this macro does not get defined for you when you get such errors for GDI+ APIs/types.
To resolve, remove any definitions of this macro (if you can find them) or undefine them at the top of your source file *before* you include any of the platform header files like so:

```
#undef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```